# Sharing moving costs with housemates

Tags: arithmetic

My housemates and I just moved and we've got a few costs associated with it as well as a refund from our previous house. Who owes who what.

There are three of us. We are receiving a refund of 848.08 to be shared evenly amongst us.

- Person One paid 27.50 for new keys, 173.50 for movers and 120 for
  cleaners.
- Person Two paid 30 for a deposit for the cleaner.
- Person Three has paid nothing.

How much does each person get back from the refund?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did Two get the deposit back?  If so, that doesn't count.  I will assume so.

Each person should net $\frac 13(848.08-27.50-173.50-120)=175.69$ with a penny left over.  Two and Three get this amount, One gets the rest.  You can check that One winds up with the same net and the penny for interest.